# How to make CQ 5 return response in JSON format?

Tags: aem

The following `curl` command creates a node in CRX:

```
curl -u admin:admin \ 
     -F”jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured” \
     -F”sling:resourceType=foo/bar” ... http://localhost:4502
```

However CQ5 returns the response in HTML format:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Content modified ...</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <h1>Content modified ...</h1>
    ...
    <p><a href="">Go Back</a></p>
    <p><a href="...">Modified Resource</a></p>
    <p><a href="/etc/tags/...-keywords">Parent of Modified Resource</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to craft the request so that the response is in JSON format?

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not there is, but it seems like the only really useful part of the page above is the status code (`201` in this case), if you don't view it in a browser — do the error pages provide more useful content that you'd need in JSON?

Comment: @anotherdave I have excluded some content from the output above to simplify this question, but the response includes a `<table>` section that contains some potentially helpful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/), on which CQ is based, selects the output format based on the request's Accept header:

```
$ curl -u admin:admin -s -H"Accept:application/json" -Ftest=ok http://localhost:8080/tmp | jq .
{
  "referer": "",
  "changes": [
    {
      "argument": "/tmp",
      "type": "created"
    },
    {
      "argument": "/tmp/test",
      "type": "modified"
    }
  ],
  "path": "/tmp",
  "location": "/tmp",
  "parentLocation": "/",
  "isCreate": true,
  "status.code": 201,
  "status.message": "Created",
  "title": "Content created /tmp"
}
```

That should work the same in CQ.

As per Sling's [PostServletOutputContentTypeTest](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/integration-tests/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/webapp/integrationtest/servlets/post/PostServletOutputContentTypeTest.java), you can also use an `:http-equiv-accept` request parameter instead of the Accept header.